# SQL Serve - How to group n lines to subnodes for xml path

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

```
declare @textline table (lineid int, textline varchar(100))

insert Into @textline (lineid, textline)
values (1, 'AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD'),
       (2, '1212 3434 5656 7878'),
       (3, 'ABCD DEFG GHIJ JKLM'),
       (4, 'AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD'),
       (5, '1212 3434 5656 7878'),
       (6, 'ABCD DEFG GHIJ JKLM')

Select TextLine Line
  From @textline       
   For Xml Path(''), Root('TextBlock')
```

> ```
> -- The result as 
> <TextBlock>
>   <Line>AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD</Line>
>   <Line>1212 3434 5656 7878</Line>
>   <Line>ABCD DEFG GHIJ JKLM</Line>
>   <Line>AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD</Line>
>   <Line>1212 3434 5656 7878</Line>
>   <Line>ABCD DEFG GHIJ JKLM</Line>
> </TextBlock>
> ```

How to amend the TSQL code (SQL Server) for this expected result?

We want to group n lines (3 lines for this case), the expected result as follow:

> ```
> <TextBlock>
>   <Line>AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD</Line>
>   <Line>1212 3434 5656 7878</Line>
>   <Line>ABCD DEFG GHIJ JKLM</Line>
> </TextBlock>
> <TextBlock>
>   <Line>AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD</Line>
>   <Line>1212 3434 5656 7878</Line>
>   <Line>ABCD DEFG GHIJ JKLM</Line>
> </TextBlock>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use integer division which can be used as grouping rank

Your test scenario (changed the last digits to mark the rows for the result)

```
declare @textline table (lineid int, textline varchar(100))

insert Into @textline (lineid, textline)
values (1, 'AAAA BBBB CCCC 1111'),
       (2, '1212 3434 5656 1122'),
       (3, 'ABCD DEFG GHIJ 1133'),
       (4, 'AAAA BBBB CCCC 2211'),
       (5, '1212 3434 5656 2222'),
       (6, 'ABCD DEFG GHIJ 2233');
```

--The CTE adds a grouping rank to the result set

```
WITH Numbered AS 
(
    SELECT tl.lineid
          ,tl.textline
          ,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tl.lineid)-1)/3 AS GroupRank
    FROM @textline AS tl
)
--Each grouping rank is one row, which returns all related lines 
--The XML parts are put together with the outer `FOR XML`
SELECT (
        SELECT innerTL.textline AS Line
        FROM Numbered AS innerTL
        WHERE innerTL.GroupRank=Numbered.GroupRank
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
       )
FROM Numbered
GROUP BY GroupRank
FOR XML PATH('TextBlock');
```

The result

```
<TextBlock>
  <Line>AAAA BBBB CCCC 1111</Line>
  <Line>1212 3434 5656 1122</Line>
  <Line>ABCD DEFG GHIJ 1133</Line>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock>
  <Line>AAAA BBBB CCCC 2211</Line>
  <Line>1212 3434 5656 2222</Line>
  <Line>ABCD DEFG GHIJ 2233</Line>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a grouping column in a CTE with integer division and use that column to group by in the main query and join to the CTE again in a subquery to get the line values.

```
with C as
(
  select (row_number() over(order by T.lineid) - 1) / 3 as grp,
         T.textline,
         T.lineid
  from @textline as T
)
select (
       select C2.textline as Line
       from C as C2
       where C1.grp = C2.grp
       order by C2.lineid
       for xml path(''), type
       )
from C as C1
group by C1.grp
order by C1.grp
for xml path('TextBlock');
```